# How to call oracle stored procedure with sys_refcursor output in Java JPA DataNucleus?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, datanucleus, sys-refcursor

When I try a standard code, I get the following error message:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error encountered when extracting results for SQL query "get_person_list_sp"
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:316)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAStoredProcedureQuery.getResultList(JPAStoredProcedureQuery.java:305)
    at org.example.jpa.JPANamedSPTest.main(JPANamedSPTest.java:17)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1358)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3778)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:198)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:198)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.StoredProcedureQuery.performExecute(StoredProcedureQuery.java:444)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.StoredProcedureQuery.executeQuery(StoredProcedureQuery.java:143)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1862)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.execute(Query.java:1844)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAStoredProcedureQuery.getResultList(JPAStoredProcedureQuery.java:288)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm able to run the same code using Hibernate. Does it mean DataNucleus does not support ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR?

If anyone has working code, share here.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_person_list_sp(
    src OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN src FOR 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name 
   FROM person 
   ORDER BY 
        first_name,
        last_name;
END;

```
        query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("get_person_list_sp")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(
                        "src",
                        //void.class,
                        Class.class,
                        ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR
                );

        //query.execute();
        List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you used to generate that error as per a reproducible example? It's very difficult to offer advice without it.

Comment: You should add your code to your question instead of posting it as a comment :)